# Runtime class name for the view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a way to get the actual type of the class generated for the view? For example, a view in SomeFolder/Edit.cshtml gets converted to a class of ASP._Page_Views_SomeFolder_Edit_cshtml by the runtime. How can we get this type/classname?

Comment: Why do you want the class type?

Comment: Well, I was looking into something and was wondering if it is possible and if so how. Why is not that important.

Comment: Why's always important because there might be another way to approach the problem, that's why I asked.

Comment: 10 years later: I'd love to use `nameof()` to insert the view name in my C# Controller methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a view (Razor):

```
<div>@this.GetType()</div>
```

and if you are using WebForms:

```
<div><%= this.GetType() %></div>
```

As to the usefulness of doing such thing stays a complete mystery to me. Hope it makes sense to you.

Comment: Thanks but not from within the view itself but from somewhere else (say from global.aspx.cs's Application derived class). Sorry, should have mentioned earlier.

Comment: @amit_g: You want to do something along the lines of enumerating the views or what?  How would you get a hold of a view class from global.asax?